# Removing buttons with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
// Makes letters for the chosen word.
function letterMaker() {
    for (i=0; i<word.length; i++) {
        var button = document.createElement("input")
        button.type = "submit"
        button.value = ""
        button.setAttribute('class', 'letter');
        document.getElementById("field").appendChild(button);
        }
    }

// Removes letters.
function letterRemover() {
    var button = document.getElementById("letter");
    button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
}
```

But whenever I call out the `letterRemover()` function to remove the elements by the `id` "letter", it gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

Comment: yeah, but the button's id is not "letter". its class is.

Comment: What is calling `letterRemover`? And should it remove all letters, or just a single one?

Comment: Basically a button is considered as a letter, but I didn't get as far as removing all letters because of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

letterMaker method creates a button with a **class** 'letter'.

letterRemover method tries to remove element with **id** 'letter' and cannot find it.